# Visualize assembler and code side by side on OSX

Tags: debugging, gdb, assembly

How can I visualize the source code and the corresponding assembler generated by a compiler (does not matter, but it's gfortran) on OSX ? gdb shows either one or the other (`disas` shows the assembler, `ls` shows the code). Under linux, objdump perform this service, but I am not able to find anything relevant for OSX (Lion, in case).

According to gdb manual, the /m option of disassemble should perform this trick, but I get a syntax error instead.

`GNU gdb 6.3.50-20050815 (Apple version gdb-1708) (Mon Aug  8 20:32:45 UTC 2011)`

Maybe it's too old? Is there another solution on Lion?

Answer (score 0):

The 6.3 edition of gdb does not support that switch. However you can use the macports package to install the 7.3 version of gdb, which supports the /m switch. The macports package can be found at http://www.macports.org/.

Comment: I tried with fink, but apparently there's no gdb available, at least in the standard repos. Do you know if there's a non-standard one which contains it? I would prefer not to install both fink and macports.